# NX Client - 'e' key acts as backspace

Tags: nx-client

I am using NoMachines NX Client 3.4.0-8 for Mac OS X to connect to NX Server Version 3.4.0-12 on Ubuntu. For some reason, when I use the 'e' key, it is interpreted as a backspace. I tried using [this solution](http://faculty.virginia.edu/comp-phys/phys2660/wiki/doku.php?id=osx_nxclient_keyboard_fix), but it did not work for me. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The fix you linked to is *almost* correct; it assumes you run `csh`, whereas both OS X and Ubuntu use `bash`.  You want to add the following line to `.bash_profile` instead of their change to `.login`:

```
xmodmap fix-e-key-for-mac.xmodmap >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried another key board, my junky Microsoft keyboard had a similar problem and I  and purchased a new one and fixed the problem. also Em running windows xp and seven so it could be a entirely different issue on your part.